# Google apps script function returns undefined in html

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-apps-script, undefined

I am building an add-on for google docs (Just for practice) that will act like email. I already incorporated sending, receiving, deleting, and viewing messages. I added the code needed for a UI modal dialog, but one of the functions is only returning `undfined`. I tested this function in the `code.gs` file, and it worked perfectly. Here is a section of `code.gs`:

```
function onInstall() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Startup').setWidth(350).setHeight(170);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'New account:');
}

function testCheck() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(checkUsername(ui.prompt('').getResponseText(), ui.prompt('').getResponseText()));
}

function checkUsername(un, em) {
  var i; var a; var is;
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (props.getProperty(un) == null) {
    is = true;
  } else {
    return 'This username is taken!';
  }
  if (em.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var len = (em.match(/@/g) || []).length;
    if (len == 1) {
      if (props.getProperty(em) != null) {
        return 'Someone has already registered this email address as ' + props.getProperty(em);
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if (em.indexOf(', ') != -1) {
        em = em.split(', ');
      } else if (em.indexOf('; ') != -1) {
        em = em.split('; ');
      } else if (em.indexOf(' + ') != -1) {
        em = em.split(' + ');
      } else if (em.indexOf(';') != -1) {
        em = em.split(';');
      } else if (em.indexOf(',') != -1) {
        em = em.split(',');
      } else if (em.indexOf('+') != -1) {
        em = em.split('+');
      } else if (em.indexOf(' ') != -1) {
        em = em.split(' ');
      } else {
        return 'Please separate your email addresses with a comma, space, or semicolon.';
      }
      for (i = 0; i < em.length; i++) {
        a = em[i];
        if (props.getProperty(a) != null) {
          return 'Someone has already registered ' + a + ' as ' + props.getProperty(a);
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Username:<br>
    <input type='text' id='user' style='width:350px' maxlength='12'/><br>
    Other email addresses:<br>
    <textarea id='extras' style='width:350px' rows='2'></textarea><br>
    <span class='error' id='err'></span><br>
    <button class='action' onClick='check()'>Next</button>
    <button onclick='group()'>Groups</button><br>
    <script>
      function check() {
        var un = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var em = document.getElementById('extras').value;
        var fail = document.getElementById('err');
        var is = google.script.run.checkUsername(un, em);
        if (typeof is == 'string') {
          fail.innerHTML = is;
        } else {
          google.script.host.close();
          google.script.run.setAccount(un, em);
        }
      }

      function group() {
        var un = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var em = document.getElementById('extras').value;
        var is = google.script.run.checkUsername(un, em);
        if (typeof is == 'boolean') {
          setGroupAddress(un, em);
        } else {
          document.getElementById('err').innerHtml = is;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update:** I completely retyped the functions, but the program continues to return undefined. All inputs are the correct values, and the function returns information correctly in a `ui.alert()` box.

Comment: What is the name of the function that is returning `undefined`?

Comment: `checkUsername()`

Comment: You need to debug your code.  In script tags, you need to use `console.log()` statements.  In server side ".gs" files, you need to use `Logger.log()` statements.  Before each client side call to `google.script.run.checkUsername(un, em)` put two `console.log` statements.  `console.log('un: ' + un)`  Run the code and look in the browser console.  In Chrome and Firefox, press the f12 key to open the browsers console, and view the log.  Are the parameters `un, em` being passed to `checkUsername(un, em)`?  We could do that for you, but that's something you should be able to do yourself.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can open a modal window from the onInstall simple trigger (however, I can't find the docs to prove that) I think what you want to do is add an addon menu to the toolbar and open the modal window that way.

Comment: @JordanRhea You can use output a modal window from the trigger, since onInstall() runs in authMode.Full

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms interesting! that is very good to know. so when you install your addon it opens a modal window?

Comment: @JordanRhea Yes. You can use this feature for things like introductory tours to complicated add-ons, or getting user preferences like metric/standard units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after completely reading the Google Apps Script Documentation. The `google.script.run.function()` API *does not return a value*. In order to fetch data from a script, you must have the script generate raw HTML, and create a dialog with an HTML string.

Comment: They do return a value, in the sense that they call a handler function with it. So `.withSuccessHandler(myLocalFoo)` will mean your apps script function sends its output to the client function `myLocalFoo()`

Answer (score 0):

Due to security considerations, scripts cannot directly return HTML to a browser. Instead, they must sanitize it so that it cannot perform malicious actions. You can return sanitized HTML using the createHtmlOutput API

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}
```

The code in the HtmlOutput can include embedded JavaScript and CSS. (This is standard client-side JavaScript that manipulates the DOM, not Apps Script). All of this content is sanitized using Google Caja, which applies some limitations to your client-side code. For more information, see the guide to restrictions in HTML service.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#